# PHP: Emails only working for certain email clients

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ion-auth

I am creating a site which uses Codeigniter and Ion Auth Library.

I have set up a registration/login/forgot password which all works apart from an issue for the forgot password setup.

If the users email address is using hotmail,yahoo,gmail and so on they receive the email fine, are able to reset the password and the data changes in the database.

I am having problems with personal domain email addresses receiving this email, in outlook and   Mail so it looks like it could be something to do with Exchange?

I have also enabled the log settings on a computer which has outlook and when test sending an email nothing is logged so it's not like it's blocking the email.

Now i have an array with the email config settings and i am unsure if it could be something to do with the host,protocol, headers?! or any other settings but i will provide some information below to what i have. If anyone has any information, links, snippets or ideas this would be a great help.

With using Ion Auth i have just kept the code where it was and changed it to my settings in the config file:

**CONFIG**

```
   $config['use_ci_email'] = FALSE; // Send Email using the builtin CI email class, if false it will return the code and the identity
    $config['email_config'] = array(
        'protocol'=> 'mail',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' =>'utf-8',
        'smpt_host' =>'smpt.url.com',
        'smpt_user'=> 'ssl://smtp.live.com',
        'smtp_port' => '25',
        'validate' => TRUE,
        'priority' => 1

    );
```

**Controller for Forgot Password**:

```
//forgot password
    function forgot_password() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            //setup the input
            $this->data['email'] = array('name' => 'email',
                'id' => 'email',
            );

            if ( $this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth') == 'username' ){
                $this->data['identity_label'] = 'Username';
            }else{
                $this->data['identity_label'] = 'Email';
            }

            //set any errors and display the form
            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');
            $this->_render_page('forgot_password', $this->data);
        }else{
            // get identity for that email
            $config_tables = $this->config->item('tables', 'ion_auth');
            $identity = $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'))->limit('1')->get($config_tables['users'])->row();

            //run the forgotten password method to email an activation code to the user
            $forgotten = $this->ion_auth->forgotten_password($identity->{$this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth')});

            if ($forgotten) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                redirect("login", 'refresh'); //we should display a confirmation page here instead of the login page
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                redirect("forgot_password", 'refresh');
            }
        }
    }


    function _get_csrf_nonce() {
        $this->load->helper('string');
        $key = random_string('alnum', 8);
        $value = random_string('alnum', 20);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfkey', $key);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('csrfvalue', $value);

        return array($key => $value);
    }
```

**Library function for Forgot Password:**

```
/**
     * forgotten password feature
     **/
    public function forgotten_password($identity)    //changed $email to $identity
{
        if ( $this->ion_auth_model->forgotten_password($identity) )   //changed
        {
            // Get user information
            $user = $this->where($this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth'), $identity)->users()->row();  //changed to get_user_by_identity from email

            if ($user)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'identity'      => $user->{$this->config->item('identity', 'ion_auth')},
                    'forgotten_password_code' => $user->forgotten_password_code
                );

                if(!$this->config->item('email_config', 'ion_auth'))
                {
                    $this->set_message('forgot_password_successful');
                    return $data;
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = $this->load->view($this->config->item('email_templates', 'ion_auth').$this->config->item('email_forgot_password', 'ion_auth'), $data, true);
                    $this->email->clear();
                    $this->email->from($this->config->item('admin_email', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth'));
                    $this->email->to($user->email);
                    $this->email->subject($this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('email_forgotten_password_subject'));
                    $this->email->message($message);

                    if ($this->email->send())
                    {
                        $this->set_message('forgot_password_successful');
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->set_error('forgot_password_unsuccessful');
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set_error('forgot_password_unsuccessful');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->set_error('forgot_password_unsuccessful');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: <strike>Have you looked at the email logs on host.url.com?</strike> Are you using live for email? If so do you have access to a dev mail server for testing first?

Comment: I am currently developing on a localhost and also uploaded onto a server and no relevant information received. When debugging it say's that the email was sent but said that emails may not be able to read MIME encoded emails -  not sure if this is something i could alter in my config file? Also tried plain text, striped everything back but still not luck or even errors. i have used @hotmail.co.uk and the email is received in the  outlook live browser, gmail browser and yahoo browser. I dont have access to a dev mail server unfortunately.

Comment: Can you install something like hMail Server locally to test mail sending locally first? You really could do with seeing the mail server's actual logs.

Comment: I am limited to what i can install and where within the company restrictions and access. I tried opening the library/scripts file for Mail but i dont have access to it. On another computer which uses Windows, i have enabled the log system and nothing shows up for it... trying to narrow it down as much as i can but hit a wall at the moment.

Comment: To send email when developing locally, you could use gmail `$config = Array(
   'protocol'  => 'smtp',
   'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
   'smtp_port' => 465,
   'smtp_user' => 'whatever@gmail.com',
   'smtp_pass' => '',
  );`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact config that you need. Whatever here is my own **send_mail()** function to use with **CI email library**. It may help you. However I always use ION AUTH and i never faced problem in sending mail.

```
/*
 * Send an email. 
 * $info array must have following information :
 * $info = array(
 *      'to_email'      => 
 *      'to_name'       =>
 *      'from_email'    =>
 *      'from_name'     =>
 *      'subject'       =>
 *      'body'          =>
 *      'reply_to'      =>
 * )
 */
if ( ! function_exists('send_email'))
{
    function send_email($info)
    {
        $CI = & get_instance();

        // ==========================================================================================
        $CI->load->library('email');

        $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
        $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';

        $CI->email->initialize($config);

        $CI->email->clear();
        $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        // =========================================================================================

        $CI->email->from($info['from_email'], $info['from_name']);
        $CI->email->to($info['to_email'], $info['to_name']);
        $CI->email->cc('mahbub.kuet@gmail.com', 'MAHBUB');

        $CI->email->subject($info['subject']);
        $CI->email->message($info['body']);

        $CI->email->reply_to($info['reply_to'], "No reply");

        if($CI->email->send()) return TRUE;

        return FALSE;   
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same Problem too at this moment. Here is my Solution, based on this Forum Post, which really helped me to understand this error.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewreply/785297/

In my Case, the Problem was my multilanguage Setup for IonAuth using the Language Files from the Repository. In the german Language File you will find the special character 'ü' for the 'email_forgotten_password_subject' language line.

The Codeigniter Mail Class is not using the encoding from the config for the Subject. So the specialchar got encoded bad, and an smtp_mailer Error appeared.

I've created a file application/libraries/MY_Email.php to hook the used subject setter method with this content:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Email extends CI_Email
{
    /**
     * Set Email Subject
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    void
     */
    function subject($subject)
    {
        $subject = '=?'. $this->charset .'?B?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
        $this->_set_header('Subject', $subject);
    }
}
```

Now the Mailclass is encoding the Subject the right way and we all go into the weekend and drink some beer.

I hope my Solution is matching your Problem.

Cheers